# Get array from string

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I have string example `1234567899999987654321112309101`

```
First 3 characters is data0
Second 2 characters is data1
Third 9 characters is data2
Fourth 5 characters is data3
Fifrt 12 characters is data4
```

```
First: 123
Second: 45
Third: 678999999
Fourth: 87654
Fifth: 321112309101
```

How can I split this string in array with not same data length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function:

```
$str = '1234567899999987654321112309101';
$res = [];
$res[] = substr($str,0,3);    // chars 1-3
$res[] = substr($str,3,2);    // chars 4-5
$res[] = substr($str,5,9);    // chars 6-14
$res[] = substr($str,14,5);   // chars 15-19
$res[] = substr($str,19,12);  // chars 20-31
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 678999999
    [3] => 87654
    [4] => 321112309101
)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/c9gkE)**

If the string is too big and you have a defined array of length values you can use this loop:

```
$str = '1234567899999987654321112309101';

$len = [3,2,9,5,12];

$res = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($len as $ind => $l){
    $res['data'.$ind] = substr($str,$i,$l);
    $i += $l;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [data0] => 123
    [data1] => 45
    [data2] => 678999999
    [data3] => 87654
    [data4] => 321112309101
)
```

**[Demo2](https://3v4l.org/6FdQA)**

Comment: Okay, i know for this solution, but is there any inline solution? I have 2048 length string with over 100 data.

Comment: @Zuck19, check it.

Comment: @AksenP He is mentioning that over 100 data is there so both solution wont work, In the question he need to specify the distribution of length of the data.

Comment: @Zuck19 That should be in the question. Your question is too minimal. It is unclear that `with not same data length` can vary by data points. Add three samples and how they should be separated.

Comment: @Ajith, you're not the OP. He had defined lengths of a several datas, so, he can create `$len` array very easy.